# How do i put my player on the Terrain ? The player is way down under the Terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

The Main Camera the Player/s all down under the Terrain.
Before the Terrain i had a Plane but i deleted the Plane and added Terrain.

I changed the Terrain resolution to 2000 on 2000. And using the Terrain ToolKit.

When i'm running the game i see the player drop down under the Terrain.

The player scale and position are: Position: X = -1.7, Y = 2, Z = 1
And the player Scale: X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1

The Terrain Position: X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 0
Terrain Scale: X = 0.9, Y = 0.9, Z = 2.5

What i want is when running the game that the player camera other players all will be on the Terrain or if it's the camera a bit above it like it was when the Plane was instead.

This is a screenshot example show where the Main Player is same the camera guards the light.

[image: Terrain]

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

You can manually drag the players and camera above the terrain and setup their position as you need.

Otherwise you can set `transform.position` Vector3 above terrain `transform.position` Vector3 at `Start()` in the character controller script. If your camera have a following script in it, then it will be above the player as well as player. Else you have to do the same for camera.

Another way, you can manually drag the terrain under players and characters or set position under these at `Start()` of terrain.